# AngularJS & ES6: Service not logging as expected

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6

I'm unable to get my AngularJS services to function with ES6. This is super simplified but I still can't seem to get it to work!

The code doesn't throw any errors.

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/tuvelek/edit?js,console,output)

```
// basic template
const template = '<h1>Super Bowl Quarterbacks (logged)</h1>';

// AppStore class
class AppStore {
  constructor($log) {
    this.$log = $log;
  }

  logName() {
    this.$log.log('Tom Brady');
    this.$log.log('Nick Foles');
  }
}

// Controller class
class Controller {
  constructor(AppStore) {
    AppStore.logName();
  }
}

// Component object
const component = {
  bindings: {},
  template: template,

// Per estus post, this solved my initial issue of not getting logging to work
  controller: Controller
};

// app component
angular.module('app',[])
.component('app', component)

// Per estus post, this solved unknown provider error
.service('AppStore', AppStore);
```

Edit: updated code and jsbin. I notated what was changed in order for it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ES6 sugared syntax

```
const component = {
  /*...*/
  Controller
};
```

is corresponding to ES5

```
const component = {
  /*...*/
  Controller: Controller
};
```

While a component is expected to have `controller` property.

It should be:

```
const component = {
  bindings: {},
  template,
  controller: Controller
};
```

Comment: estus - Thank you for the reply! That solved one part, now I receive an error on my service: unknown provider AppStore. I've updated the jsbin as well as my initial post.

Comment: Because you haven't registered it as provider? You don't have `.service('AppStore', AppStore)` anywhere, and you should.